# Help defining a vector space such that each element of a vector is a real number apart from the 7th element which is positive real number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some help defining a vector space $\mathcal{X}$ containing vectors $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{7}$ such that each 7th element of every vector has the following property $\{x_{i}\in\textbf{x}:0\le x_{7}\}$.

Is there anyway to write this in a good mathematical format to write this so that I can make a set later on as follows: $X\subseteq\mathcal{X}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your scaling and how is this a vector space?

Comment: @Randall the scaling is scalar multiplication and is communitive so $c\cdot\textbf{x} = c\cdot\textbf{x} = c\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}c$

And you are right it wouldn’t be a vector space as the inverse elements of vector addition would not word due to the 7th element in the vector. Then what would the name of this set be?

Comment: Right that was my question: you’re not closed under scaling by negatives.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this set is not a vector space. As for the notation, it is essentially already contained in your question:
$$\mathcal{X}=\{(x_1,\dots,x_7)\in\Bbb{R}^7: 0\leq x_7\}.$$